# How to convert the (clob data) rows into columns

Tags: oracle, pivot-table, multiple-columns, rows, clob

I need to pivot the clob data into multiple columns, basically, I want to convert the clob data rows into columns.

```
create table staff (
name varchar2(200),
month varchar2(20),
staff_names clob);

insert into staff values ('Vijay','Jan','staff_name_1');
insert into staff values ('Vijay','Jan','staff_name_2');
insert into staff values ('Vijay','Jan','staff_name_3');
insert into staff values ('Vijay','Jan','staff_name_4');
insert into staff values ('Vijay','Jan','staff_name_5');
insert into staff values ('Vijay','Jan','staff_name_6');
insert into staff values ('Vijay','Jan','staff_name_7');
insert into staff values ('Vijay','Jan','staff_name_8');
insert into staff values ('Vijay','Jan','staff_name_9');
insert into staff values ('Vijay','Jan','staff_name_10');
insert into staff values ('Vijay','Jan','staff_name_11');
insert into staff values ('Vijay','Jan','staff_name_12');
insert into staff values ('Vijay','Jan','staff_name_13');
...
insert into staff values ('Vijay','May','staff_name_13');

select name, month, wm_concat(staff_name) from staff group by name, month;
```

and output is

[image]

Here numbers is (56, 39, 70, 90, 52)-  total number of staff names concatenated.

I want to see all the staff names for each month, working under each manager alias name
Note: Here i am showing single manager 'Vijay'

```
select
    name,
    case when month='Jan' then all_names
    end as Jan,
    case when month='Feb' then all_names
    end as Feb,
    case when month='Mar' then all_names
    end as Mar,
    case when month='Apr' then all_names
    end as Apr,
    case when month='May' then all_names
    end as May
from
(select name, month, wm_concat(staff_name) as all_names from staff group by name, month);
```

Output of my select statement is coming like this

[image]

but my expected output should be like this

[image]

If this is about the numbers, I can use Max/Count respectively. Here I am looking for non-numeric data.
I also tried pivot, but because I have clob data in staff_name column, I am not able to use pivot and decode as well. Because both have a limitation of 4000 characters. I am open to any suggestions.

Comment: select name, month, wm_concat(staff_name) from staff group by name, month;  did you run this on staff_names as a clob column and got the said results in question ? I wonder cos it doest run here, it appears that lob data type have lot of limitations, was not meant to be used in this way.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the wm_concat is, anyway

You don't need to use `case when`, you should use `pivot` as Below:

```
select 
* 
from 
(
select 
t.name,
t.month,
t.staff_names
from staff t
)
pivot (
count(staff_names)--<aggregation function>
For month in ([Jan],[Feb],[Mar],[Apr] )
)
```

I suggest you study the `pivot in oracle`

Comment: This solution is likely to work with varchar2, but not [with the clob datatype](https://dbfiddle.uk/faA_qXrg).